# Sobre codigo en js

Tags: javascript

Mi pregunta es en relacion a la siguiente consigna:
Y sí, solo nos falta practicar la sintaxis de una arrow function que reciba más de un parámetro. Tomemos la función saludar(), que esta vez recibe un nombre y un apellido, y veamos de convertirla en una arrow function.

Mi código es este:

```
let saludar = (nombre, apellido) => "Hola," + nombre + " " + apellido + "!";
console.log(saludar)
```

No se por qué no se ejecuta.
Soy nueva en programación, estoy aprendiendo y no llego a la respuesta aunque se que es fácil!
Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.
Gracias.

Comment: No se ejecuta porque no la estás usando correctamente, para ejecutar una función en JS, debes usar su nombre seguido de paréntesis y los argumentos dentro separados por coma. Si pruebas `console.log(saludar("Sabrina", "Basoa"));`, seguro que funcionará. Saludos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio!!! ahora si se ejecutó el código. Gracias!